# Adding Image to an Object with Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

Trying to replace the black square with a png image.
Not sure the proper technique.

the image I want to use -

[image]

### Below is the codepen where the example lives.

https://codepen.io/roys/pen/pJGJON

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var h = window.innerHeight;
var w = window.innerWidth;

canvas.height = h;
canvas.width = w;

function drawRectangle(rect) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
  context.fillStyle = rect.color;
  context.fill();    
}

//moving rectangle
var mover = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
  color: '#000',
  down: true,
  right: true
}

function animate() {
  clear();
  render();
  rID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function clear() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function render() {
  //set direction
  if (mover.down && mover.y >= h-mover.height) 
    mover.down = false;
  
  if (!mover.down && mover.y <= 0) 
    mover.down = true;
  
  if (mover.right && mover.x >= w-mover.width) 
    mover.right = false;
  
  if (!mover.right && mover.x <= 0) 
    mover.right = true;
  
  //make move
  if (mover.right)
    mover.x += 10;
  else 
    mover.x -= 10;
  
  if (mover.down)
    mover.y += 10;
  else 
    mover.y -= 10;
  
  drawRectangle(mover);
}

animate();
```

```css
body,
#canvas 
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I still don't understand how to implement that into my code though. @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan I can't use that answer with this issue. Can you help me understand how to integrate the two pieces?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2sqcum4r/